# How to scale Canvas shapes?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Please check out this code :

```
    (function() {
        var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
        if (cnv.getContext) {
          var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
        } else {
          alert('God Damn it ...');
        }

        function initialize() {
            window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
            resizeCanvas();
        }

        function draw() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {

            width = Math.random() * cnv.width;
            height = Math.random() * cnv.height;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(width, height, 15, 0, Math.PI * 2);
            ctx.strokeStyle = '#E1E1E1';
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;

            ctx.stroke();
          }
        }

        function resizeCanvas() {
            cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
            cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
            draw();
        }

        initialize();

    })();
```

I have created 25 Circle shape with random position and I want to create an animation that scales up or down in a interval time. I know about `setInterval` but how should I call my shape to do something on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you will want to do is to have a place to store the position of your circles, since they are all going to be the same radius we can just store the `x` and `y` position. For that we can create a `Circle` function (*"class"*) and have an array of circles:

```
  var circles = [];      // Array to store our circles
  var minRadius = 1;     // The smallest radius we can hit
  var maxRadius = 100;   // The largest radius we can hit
  var currentRadius = 15;// The current radius of all our circles
  var scaleBy = 1;       // How the radius changes  
  var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  // ...

  function initialize() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    resizeCanvas();  
    // Populating the array of circles to use when drawing
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) { // Make sure to do this after re-sizing the canvas
      width = Math.random() * cnv.width;
      height = Math.random() * cnv.height;
      circles.push(new Circle(width, height));
    }
  }
  // ...
  function Circle(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  Circle.prototype.draw = function(){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, currentRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#E1E1E1';
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.stroke();
  }
```

Now that you have some circles when you call `draw` you can iterate through the array and call `circle.draw()` for each circle element in your array:

```
  function draw() {
    // Clear the screen and draw the circles in our array
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
      circles[i].draw();
    }
  }
```

One note is you will want to use `ctx.clearRect(0,0, cnv.width, cnv.height)` to clear the screen before drawing.

Finally you can now use `setInterval` to change the `currentRadius` (*While there is nothing wrong with `setInterval` I'd recommend using `window.requestAnimationFrame` for animation as it's a bit more smooth and efficient method). Then when you call `draw` it will draw the circles with the new value of `currentRadius`. In this example I'm going to have it start at `15`. Then increase by `1` until it hits `maxRadius`, then we can flip the sign of `scaleBy` to start decreasing the radius to make them smaller. Finally when it his our `minRadius` you can flip the sign of `scaleBy` again to make it start scaling up again:

```
  var timer = setInterval( function(){
    // If we hit our min or max start scaling in the other direction
    if(currentRadius > maxRadius || currentRadius < minRadius){
      scaleBy *= -1;
    }
    currentRadius += scaleBy;
    draw();
  }, 50);
```

Below is a code snippet of the complete program:

```js
(function() {
  var circles = [];
  var minRadius = 1;
  var maxRadius = 100;
  var currentRadius = 15;
  var scaleBy = 1;
  var cnv = document.getElementById('canvas');
  if (cnv.getContext) {
    var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
  } else {
    alert('God Damn it ...');
  }

  function initialize() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
    resizeCanvas();  
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      width = Math.random() * cnv.width;
      height = Math.random() * cnv.height;
      circles.push(new Circle(width, height));
    }
  }

  function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, cnv.width, cnv.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < circles.length; i++) {
   circles[i].draw();
    }
  }

  function resizeCanvas() {
    cnv.width = window.innerWidth;
    cnv.height = window.innerHeight;
  }
  
  function Circle(x, y){
   this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  
  Circle.prototype.draw = function(){
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, currentRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#E1E1E1';
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.stroke();
  }

  initialize();
  var timer = setInterval( function(){
   if(currentRadius > maxRadius || currentRadius < minRadius){
      scaleBy *= -1;
    }
    currentRadius += scaleBy;
    draw();
  }, 50);

})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Can you please give me an example of moving shapes? Change directions about 10px around themselves for example. Can I do that without Classes and ..., I mean more easily ... :)

Comment: @AliBahaari Do you want them moving around in a circle around a central point?

Comment: No I meansomething like itpersia.studio background. :)

Comment: @AliBahaari I'm not sure what that looks like? Would it be moving in a single direction and bouncing off walls?

Comment: No It moves to random position in every interval but because of short time, It moves little and with this movement, It rotates and scale up and down randomly. Sorry I ask many questions my friend. :)